# CakePhp - Dinamically added fields on form not being recognized

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm having trouble with dynamically adding fields to one of my CTP files and having it be recognized by cake.

Basically, what I'm doing is as follows. Here the code is displaying the data that already exists on the database with a button at the end that lets the users add new fields:

```
    
    echo $this->Html->div(null, null, array('class'=>'col-md-12'));
        echo '<legend>Cursos Extras</legend>';
            echo $this->Html->div(null, null, array('class'=>'cursos_extras'));
                $i = 0;
                foreach($cursosExtras as $curso){
                    echo '<div><input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso'.$i.'][nome]"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso'.$i.'][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label><a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1"><img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover"></a></div>';
                    $i++;
                }
    
    echo $this->Html->tag('/div');

    echo $this->Html->div(null, null, array('class'=>'col-md-12'));
        echo $this->Html->div(null, null, array('class'=>'col-md-12'));
            echo $this->Form->button('Adicionar curso', array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-md', 
                'style' => 'margin-top:10px', 
                'type'=>'button', 
                'wrapInput' => 'col-md-12',
                'id'=>'adicionarCursoExtraBtn'));
            echo $this->Html->tag('/div');  
        echo $this->Html->tag('/div');
    echo $this->Html->tag('/div');
```

here is the Jquery that adds such fields:

```
    var cursos_extras_count = <?php echo count($cursosExtras) ?>; //initlal text box count
    
    $(document).on("click","#adicionarCursoExtraBtn", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper_cursos).append(
                '<div><input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso'+cursos_extras_count+'][nome]"><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso'+cursos_extras_count+'][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label><a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1"><img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover"></a></div>'
                ); //add input box
            x++; //text box increment
            cursos_extras_count++;
        }else{
            alert('Numero máximo de campos preenchidos');
        }
    });
```

This is what I got after adding 2 new fields using the button (curso0 and curso1 were already on the DB, so they are being generated by the foreach loop, while curso2 and curso3 are being appended using the Jquery):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <legend>Cursos Extras</legend>
  <div class="cursos_extras">
    <div>
      <input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso0][nome]">
      <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso0][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label>
      <a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1">
        <img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso1][nome]">
      <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso1][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label>
      <a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1">
        <img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso2][nome]">
      <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso2][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label>
      <a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1">
        <img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input size="30" maxlength="20" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso3][nome]">
      <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Servidor][cursos_extras][curso3][detran]" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-right: 1rem">Realizado no Detran</label>
      <a style="float:initial" href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1">
        <img src="/apps/banco_talento/theme/Template/img/acoes/remover.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" alt="" data-original-title="Remover">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="margin-top:10px" type="button" wrapinput="col-md-12" id="adicionarCursoExtraBtn">Adicionar curso
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach works just fine with everything else in my code. However, in this case, it seems that cake simply wont recognize the new fields. When I debug the data on the controller, it only presents curso0 and curso1, but never the fields that were added using Jquery.

I've tried other approaches, such as generating the HTML in the controller and passing it back to the CTP as JSON using AJAX (I'm using the same approach for other things in my case and it works just fine) but basically the same thing happens. The code generated seems to be exactly what I wanted, but Cake doesn't seem to recognize the newly added fields.

ps: This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if the explanation and/or the English are not that clear.

Comment: Is `cursos_extras` in your `_accessible` list on the relevant entity? If not, nothing you pass in there will be patched into it.

Comment: It would make sense since it doesnt matter the aproach that i use the result is aways the same, and it is only happening with "cursos_extrar". How can I check if that is the case? @GregSchmidt

Comment: Look at the `_accessible` property in the entity class, as [described here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment).

Comment: @GregSchmidt I guess it doesn't seem to be the case. "cursos_extras" didn't have a _accessible  property as described in the cookbook (It might be an older version of cake?). I tried to add it and setting only the "*" setting (both as true and false, just to be sure) but it still only recognized the fields added with the foreach loop and not thoses appended with Jquery

Comment: It wouldn't be the `cursos_extras` entity, but the entity where that's a property. Servidor? What version of CakePHP are you working with? The whole "data[...]" structure looks like it might be old, in which case none of this would apply.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I did check it in Servidor. But indeed, The project is using cake 2.5.5, so I guess none of this apply right?

Comment: No, my comments above were related to Cake 3.x and above. There's no such thing as entities in 2.x.